# вывести на экран разницу значений индексов в цикле

Tags: python, pandas

Прошу помочь. Уровень изучения - начальный. Третий день не могу понять в чем  я ошибаюсь при написании кода, второй раз прошла ранее изученные материалы, но ошибки не поняла своей. Без этого не могу пойти дальше.. До этого пропустила решение пары задач, потом вернулась и уже решила.

Задача такая:

1. Список `campaign_weeks` хранит номера недель, в которые проводились рекламные кампании. Они соответствуют индексам значений в списках `payments` и `installs`.
   Для каждой недели в `campaign_weeks` посчитайте разницу между числом установок (`installs`) в эту неделю и в предыдущую. Чтобы обратиться к значению предыдущей недели, вычтите из индекса единицу прямо в квадратных скобках. Результаты сохраните в списке `installs_from_ads`, чтобы функция `print()` вывела их на экран.
   Вот такая подсказка и вроде я все сделала в соответствии с ней, но решение не верно.

Объявите переменную `installs_from_ads` и сохраните в ней пустой список. Затем напишите цикл `for`: для каждого элемента в списке `campaign_weeks` найдите разницу значений `installs[...]` и `installs[... - 1]` и добавьте результат в список `installs_from_ads` методом `.append()`. Вместо **`...`** подставьте название переменной цикла.

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('app_stats.csv')

payments = list(data['payments']) # список с числом платежей
installs = list(data['installs']) # список с числом установок

campaign_weeks = [7, 9, 13, 15, 17, 19, 29, 31, 33, 45]

installs_from_ads=[]

for i in range(len(campaign_weeks)):
    
    installs_from_ads.append(installs[i]-installs[i-1])
    
print(installs_from_ads)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, len(campaign_weeks)):
```

иначе для первой недели вы получаете разницу с последней.

Нужно ли что-то делать для первой недели (допустим, installs[0]) вносить в список - в условии не определено

Comment: неверный ответ, изменение кода не принесло рез-та.. я писала цикл for  и вот этот код installs_from_ads.append(installs[i]-installs[i-1]), значит в этом коде ошибка.. только мне не очевидно какая.

Comment: С первой (0) неделей что делали? Списки installs проверяли? Формат вывода списка такой, как требуется?

Comment: формат вывода списка корректен, некорректно значение . я внесла изменения в код, в соответствии с рекомендацией: for i in range(1, len(campaign_weeks)):
    
    installs_from_ads.append(installs[i]-installs[i-1]) При проверке пишет неверное значение переменной installs_from_ads При сравнении рез-тов1344, 1140, 2391, -393, 944, 206, 14178, -13327, 14213] - это наш
error 
[14178, 14213, 17028, 12384, 19370, 13768, 11324, 13020, 19840, 15429]- это который корректный

Comment: Ещё раз про первую неделю напомню. Например, можно сделать installs_from_ads=[installs[0]]

Comment: Списки installs смотрели глазами?

Comment: в соответствии с подсказкой, которая обычно содержит список рекомендуемых действий, таких действий, как указываете Вы- не требуется. еще раз вот текст подсказки:  Объявите переменную installs_from_ads и сохраните в ней пустой список. Затем напишите цикл for: для каждого элемента в списке campaign_weeks найдите разницу значений installs[...] и installs[... - 1] и добавьте результат в список installs_from_ads методом .append(). Вместо ... подставьте название переменной цикла. вот написанное решение- я не могу понять, что в этом решении не соответствует списку рекомендуемых действий.

Comment: Вы видите значения в installs или они от вас скрыты?

Comment: в текущей задаче скрыты, но можно попробовать вернуться в предыдущие темы и найти значения вероятно

Comment: Между прочим, в вашем ответе 9 значений, а в корректном 10

Comment: это стало после добавления 1, по Вашей рекомендации for i in range(1, len(campaign_weeks)):.... в моем коде 10, считала..

Comment: И что ваш код давал для нулевого элемента?

Comment: вопрос в том, как отнять одно значение по индексу от предыдущего, в этом задача.

Comment: для нулевого ничего не давала, я создала пустой список installs_from_ads=[], что бы в него положить разницу значений, здесь так же нужно вычитать от значений списка campaign_weeks. в общем я уверена, что в моем решении нужно просто указать где то другую переменную...

Comment: задачу решила - нужно убрать range и len, так как требуются сами значения списка, а не индексы, т.е. for i in range campaign_weeks:

Answer (score 0):

```
campaign_weeks = [7, 9, 13, 15, 17, 19, 29, 31, 33, 45]

installs_from_ads=[]

for i in range(len(campaign_weeks)):
    
    installs_from_ads.append(installs[i]-installs[i-1])
```

Да, жалко я раньше не увидел этот вопрос. Суть проблемы действительно в том, что вы совсем не используете содержимое `campaign_weeks`, а нужно его использовать:

```
for i in campaign_weeks:
    ...
```

Хотя на более продвинутом уровне эта задача решается проще, примерно так:

```
installs_from_ads = data['installs'].diff().loc[campaign_weeks].to_list()
```